# Include pipeline variables in release notifications

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am using Azure Devops (formerly VSTS) releases to deploy a project.

In my release pipeline I have a power shell task that may not succeed in ways that do not indicate a deployment failure.  I would like to alert users when these conditions arise.

I have suppressed the errors in the power shell script and am using them to control flow to subsequent pipeline tasks.

Is there a way include pipeline variables in the notifications Azure Devops sends when a deployment is complete?

Comment: You might want to look into one of the marketplace extensions. If the purpose is to simply send an email to users when a particular task succeeds or fails, the [**Send Email**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rvo.SendEmailTask) task may work for you.

Answer (score 2):

No, the notification template is not customizable and this feature was requested: [Customise VSTS email templates](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365760/customise-vsts-email-templates.html)

But you may log your pipeline variables with powershell script: Write-Host "My var: $(my_variable)"

[User-defined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#user-defined-variables)